# Who will receive messages first virtual topic subscriber or logical queue consumer?

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I am trying to use virtual topic and am unable to find answer to this question, Can anybody help?

**Question:** I am sending to topic "VirtualTopic.Test" and have a logical Queue "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Test". I have a subscriber (A) to topic and a consumer (B) to physical queue corresponding to logical queue ("Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Test"), among them (A and B) who will receive message first A or B?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee which will get the message first and if your application is dependent on ordering of this sort then I'd say it is fundamentally flawed.